# Same dbuser used to login with python and sqlclient, but with python it doesnt have same permissions

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, sql-server-2008

As you can see in below error I am using sqlalchemy.

```
E       sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Cannot drop the table 'THE_TABLE', because it does not exist or you do not have permission. (3701) (SQLExecDirectW)") [SQL: '\n                DROP TABLE DBO.THE_TABLE\n                SELECT * INTO DBO.THE_TABLE FROM DBO.#THE_TABLE_3b49da16_6ae1_4814_a232_4fdec9a5be6b\n                GRANT SELECT ON DBO.THE_TABLE TO WRITERS\n                DROP TABLE DBO.#THE_TABLE_3b49da16_6ae1_4814_a232_4fdec9a5be6b\n                COMMIT\n            ']
```

The table(THE_TABLE) does exists.

I am very new to sqlserver and related development and I am not sure which direction to move to.
So I accept the information might not be enough in question, kindly request I shall provide.

Server: **Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3)**

Comment: `THE_TABLE`  (bad name!)? Check tables   before drop/update/etc. Another point SQL settings, which server supported multi-session ?

Comment: Add `select user, db_name(),  @@SERVERNAME` to your code and show us that the user is the same and the db is the same, and the server is the same as a picture

Comment: @sepupic db name and servername are correct but; user is comming out to be `dbo` while I am connect via sqlclient which is not the username I logged in with in sqlclient or from python

Comment: You see the user dbo when you are sysadmin; this means that you use different login. Please select system_user in both cases and you'll see the difference

Comment: @sepupic Just a doubt I used same user in bother cases, while connecting to db via sqlclient and via python; I am sure about it, just when I selected `user` on these logins. I got different outs

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are talking about. I asked you to check system_user, what do you see in both cases? I repeat you one more time: when you see the user is dbo, it means that the corresponding login is sysadmin and it has no permission issue. What you have instead is permission issue because in the second case the login is different and is not sysadmin, and you can see it selecting system_user

Comment: @sepupic `select system_user, user_name(), db_name(), @@SERVERNAME` shows `domain_user, domain_user, db_name, db_host` with python and 
`db_user, dbo, db_name, db_host` with sqlclient, in both cases I used `db_user` to login to database

Comment: @PradyJord, Server cannot mistake, it's not a human. In the first case you are logged in under domain_user, and he is not sysadmin and this is the cause of your error. Or just give the permissions to this domain_user in your db, or TRY TO UNDERSTAND WHERE IS YOUR MISTAKE. What is your connection string in case of python?